# Windows 8 tiles show up blank

Tags: windows-8, start-menu, live-tiles

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

[image]

I tried turning live updates in tiles on and off but that didn't work. Reinstalling apps also didn't work.

Comment: which graphic card do you use? Update the drivers and play with the Anti Aliasing settings (FXAA)

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce GT 525M. It's the most latest one, and I'm not sure how to change it's settings.

Comment: @magicandre1981 These are my current aa settings: http://i.imgur.com/ukLNS2D.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are issues with some applications messing with live tiles. Two culprits are Sage Thumbs and FastPictureViewer. If you don't have those installed then I'd look at applications that alter or do anything with thumbnails or any image applications especially ones that mess with or add codecs. These will be the more likely suspects.

I've also heard that if thumbnails for .PNG images aren't showing up correctly in explorer that it is linked to this issue. Fixing whatever it is that is causing the issue with .PNG thumbnail, fixes this too.

Comment: I do have SageThumbs installed. But I do need that app. Is there any other similar app like SageThumb that doesn't conflict with the tiles?

Comment: No idea, I'm afraid. If you go into the settings for Sage Thumbs, it will give you the option to disable it for certain file types. Disabling it for .PNG files should fix this for you.

Comment: So I uninstalled SageThumbs (but didn't restart my PC) and 2 tiles seem to work now. Will report what changing the settings does.